# Height of the embedded object HTML

Tags: javascript, html, height, flash

I encountered small problem with Height of embedded object in html.
I want to set the height and with of the object as per height and width of the browser. I am using following code Width sets properly but when i am trying to set height 100% it will not.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="book.swf" width=100% height=100%>
```

it is working properly for width but not for height.
Is there any possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set e.g.

```
 html, body { height: 100%; }
```

Otherwise, there’s really nothing that the percentage in setting the height of the object would relate to. You may also wish to set

```
 html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank for answer. I tried this one but its still not working.

Comment: @chotai.mit, please post your code (a full example, not just one tag) and specify the browser(s) tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the actual Values of the width and height instead of procents for example :

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../Desktop/final.swf" width="349" height="171">
```

**Updated due to comment**

If you want full browser size try this links:

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/mx2004/fullscreen.htm

http://www.webdesign.org/flash-swish/flash-tutorials/making-flash-taking-the-size-of-browser.15847.html

Comment: I want full height of browser.